# How to enable python loop in pymol command line?

Tags: python, pymol

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/message/11671079/) said the script should be used within the pymol commandline. I would like to output many distances using a loop after reading [this](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Measure_Distance). But I got error message:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(resi_total_n):
                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

My code is:

```
from pymol import cmd
mol_name='name'
resi=10 # the target residue number
resi_total_n=500 # the total residue number

f=open('dist.txt','w')
resi_n=0
for i in range(resi_total_n):
    resi_n += 1
    dst=cmd.distance('tmp',mol_name+'///'+str(resi)+'/ca',mol_name+'///'+str(resi_n)+'/ca') #the alpha carbon
    f.write("%8.3f\n"%dst)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/message/22983531/) I found the answer:

When trying to do programming, better stick to Python. Save
the following as script.py and use `run script.py` from within Pymol or
just issue `pymol script.py`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run the script as a separate file. You can put the for loop all on one line, e.g.,

When you run this code:

```
for c in chains:
    print c
```

You get this error:

```
File "toplevel", line 1
for c in chains:
               ^

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

but if you write:

```
for c in chains: print(c)
```

gives output

```
A
B
C
D
```